# FinanceApp.getHistoricalStockInfo call does not return proper values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-finance-api

When I try to get the historical quotes using the following block of code, the stockInfo array is coming back empty.  Based on the criteria specified in the FinanceApp.getHistoricalStockInfo function call, I should get the prices for GOOG stock for the trading day 11/30/2012.

```
function TestMethod()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var date = new Date(2012, 11, 30);
  var retValue = FinanceApp.getHistoricalStockInfo("GOOG", date, date, 1);
  var ret = retValue.stockInfo[0];  

  Logger.log(ret);  /* This comes back as 'undefined' */
  Logger.log(retValue.close);  /* This comes back as 'undefined' */

  if (retValue != undefined && retValue.stockInfo[0] != undefined)
    Logger.log(retValue);
}
```

This method used to work properly until about 10 days ago.  I have tried posting this to the google groups forums also but no one has responded yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you put the interval of 1 day, then you will have to have difference of at lease one day between start and end date.
e.g

```
function TestMethod(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startDate = new Date(2012, 10, 30);
  var endDate = new Date(2012, 11, 1);
  var retValue = FinanceApp.getHistoricalStockInfo('GOOG', startDate, endDate, 1);
  var ret = retValue.stockInfo[0];  

  Logger.log(ret); 
  Logger.log(retValue);  
}
```